# Using scope (after where) in the model resets where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a very strange behavior of Rails 5.2 and ruby 2.6

A different sequence of method chaining gives different results.

Example #1

```rb
Erp::Packing::Session::ZonePicker.where(round_id: 3084).active.to_sql
```

gives:

```sql
SELECT \"erp_packing_sessions\".* 
FROM \"erp_packing_sessions\" 
WHERE (logged_out_at IS NULL)
 AND (started_at > '2021-01-27 23:00:00')
```

and the scope is:

```rb
scope :active, -> { not_logged_out.where('started_at > ?', Time.current.beginning_of_day) }

scope :not_logged_out, -> { where('logged_out_at IS NULL') }
```

In this example *where* condition is lost.

Example #2 I put scope first and then where condition:

```rb
Erp::Packing::Session::ZonePicker.active.where(round_id: 3084).to_sql
```

gives:

```sql
SELECT \"erp_packing_sessions\".* 
FROM \"erp_packing_sessions\" 
WHERE (logged_out_at IS NULL) 
  AND (started_at > '2021-01-27 23:00:00') 
  AND \"erp_packing_sessions\".\"round_id\" = 3084
```

This example works as expected.

We are migrating from rails 4.2 to 5.2 and getting this strange behaviour.

Could you please point out what could be the reason and if that is covered in the documentation?

Small update: interesting, if I write it as a method:

```rb
  def self.activated
    where('started_at > ?', Time.current.beginning_of_day).where('logged_out_at IS NULL')
  end
```

it works as expected.

Update 2: `Erp::Packing::Session::ZonePicker` is the subclass of  `Erp::Packing::Session::Base` where the scopes are defined. Thus could be related to this question: [inheritance of scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411452/how-can-i-add-a-scope-to-subclass-class-through-abstract-active-record)

Update 3:
Also,
`Erp::Packing::Session::ZonePicker.where(round_id: 3084).method(:active).source`   =>

```
def #{method}(*args, &block)
  scoping { @klass.#{method}(*args, &block) }
end
```

Does @klass.#{method} mean that it’s calling the scope on the class rather chaining?

Comment: This is not intentional behavior, `Model.where.scope` and `Model.scope.where` should be identical.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411452/how-can-i-add-a-scope-to-subclass-class-through-abstract-active-record

Comment: GH issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38248

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug. It worked as expected https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/c84fcdcfbc2c00a05540cdf505f69da0 Try to start remove gems from Gemfile and code from model. I assume your problem somethere there

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299289/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-klass-in-ruby) "klass" is a variable that people use when they mean "class." Class is a protected word and so can't be used as a variable name. I would assume that `@klass` here would be the actual class, ie. `User`. [Line 405](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L405) shows the `scoping` method. Is it possible that this only occurs when you have a where in your scope and you're doing a where, too?